# Android activities pile up in backstack causing OutOfMemory error

Tags: android, performance, android-activity, memory-management

I have an application that allows a user to visit user profiles from a photo gallery (think of Instagram where you can visit a profile of a user from an image, or visit a profile of a user that left a comment on the image, etc).

**PROBLEM:**

If a user continues to visit profiles and photo galleries and repeats this cycle about 10 times there are too many instances of `ViewProfile` and `Gallery` on the backstack which results in an `OutOfMemory` error. This is due to the fact that `ActivityA` calls `startActivity()` to start `ActivityB` (who can start `ActivityC` and so on) so `finish()` is not called on `ActivityA` or `ActivityB`.

**WHAT I WANT TO KNOW:**

Since the activities call other activities it is possible that the application can go a long time without calling `finish()` on the activities that are piling up on the backstack.

So my first question is this:

1) Should my `onPause()` methods be cleaning up as much as possible to reduce the activities footprint in memory?

2) Is it possible to reduce an activity's footprint to zero (or close to zero) if `finish` (therefore `onDestroy`) is not called (or can't be expected to be called in a reasonable amount of time if the user decides to wander off and explore images and profiles of other users)?

3) Am I overlooking something when it comes to the management of activities?

4) Is there a way to completely kill the activity but save its state so that when a back button is pressed it can be rebuilt as the user would expect it?

**EXAMPLE OF DESIRED BEHAVIOR:**

In the Instagram application it seems that a user can endlessly click on user profiles (from comments or likes) and then load images of these users, then visit profiles until the end of time without a crash.  Clearly they are doing something different *but I'm not sure what, exactly*.  It would appear that they go long periods of time without calling `finish` on their activities as well since one activity calls another and they maintain a backstack that can be unwound as a user clicks on the back button.

I feel like I'm doing something wrong but I don't even know if I know the right questions to ask in order to fix it.  My application works if I avoid opening lots of profiles of random users or go back "home" that will reset the state of the application.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show AndroidManifest.

Comment: I haven't read your question in detail, but to me this sounds more like a memory leak.

Comment: @XaverKapeller - under ideal situations when `ActivityA` starts `ActvitiyB` is it expected that `ActivityA` should have a low memory footprint even though `finish()` was never called?  And if the opposite is true (if `ActivityA` has a large memory footprint in the background while `ActivityB` is active) then a memory leak is likely to blame?

Comment: @XaverKapeller a paused activity still takes up memory.  This is definitely a situation you can get into.

Comment: Stopped activities still take up memory.  Only Activities that are fully garbage collected do not.  Although you can somewhat reduce memory in onStop with careful coding this isn't a 100% preventable issue.  It is one you can mitigate though.

Comment: If the Activity is stopped then `onDestroy()` will be called and then the user won't have anything to return to when they click the back button, correct?  I am hoping that they can traverse the backstack to return to previous states/activities.  I am not doing any `AsyncTasks` or threads in either Activity.

Comment: @MaxWorg stopped!=destroyed.  onStop is frequently called without calling onDestroy, for example when the user hits the home button.  onDestroy is only called when an activity is finished.

Comment: Just so that I'm clear - in an ideal world let's assume that my `onPause` releases all memory-hungry resources and my Activities are otherwise not leaking memory - can I enter into a cycle of `ActivityN` starting `ActivityN+1` forever and Android will just know what to do?

Comment: Are there advantages as far as freeing up memory by having `ActivityA.onStop()` being called when `ActivityA` starts `ActivityB`?  will Android do something different behind the scenes to ensure that memory is freed but the user can still unwind the backstack and return to ActivityA?

Comment: You won't be able to go infinitely.  If nothing else the stack itself takes memory (but really each activity takes some as well).  You can just increase the distance.  Also, onStop is always called when moving between Activities.  Its called whenever an Activity is fully covered on screen.  See the Activity lifecycle for details.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue will be your bitmaps in your case.  They use the most memory out of everything.  Do not ever hold one directly in your class.  Use an LRUCache, decide how much memory to use on Bitmaps in general, and only hold the cache keys in the Activity/fragments.  This will make sure Bitmaps use a fixed amount of memory and the increase from additional activities is just the size of the key.  A 2 level cache (memory cache and a disk cache) is a good idea.  Depending on how bad the problem is, you may even want to go to the extreme of nulling out your ImageViews drawables in onPause so that reference isn't kept around either.  It may be necessary in your case.

In more general solutions, you need to do just what you think-  in onStop you need to jettison what you can from memory and reload it again in onStart, either from disk or from the network, preferring disk where possible.  Data structures shared between activities should not be stored multiple places in memory, they should be shared via a service or singleton.  You can't 100% stop this problem (the user can always decide to visit 1000 profiles), but if you prevent memory hogging resources from being replicated you can make it one they almost have to try to get to.

Comment: I will go take a second look at my MAT heap analysis and see if I can free up more resources.  Assuming that I have *everything* cleared/nulled, etc then each Activity that doesn't call finish() and starts another Activity will maintain a very small memory footprint?

Comment: It should.  Views are a bit heavy, but not horrific.  Images are the main thing-  you'd ideally like to see little to no increase in bitmaps as you add activities.

Comment: If that is the case then you are probably on point with you answer (in regards to bitmaps being the culprit).  I will go investigate this and get back to you.  If I have a `ListView` that is loading a bunch of views with `ImageView`s in them would I have to null out each `ImageView` that is in each position of the list adapter? Or is it enough to do adapter.clear(); adapter=null?

Comment: That's actually a good question, I'm not sure I know the answer to it.  I haven't had to try, I haven't had a recursive listview situation before.  I would think you'd have to clear them out, but not for each position in the adapter-  just for each row of the listview (iterating over listview's children).  I'd try just clearing the adapter first though, that's much easier.